# Angular UI sortable connected lists with labeled sections

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to get UI sortable with connected lists to play nice. Basically, I want to keep the functionality of two connected lists but I'd like the list on the right side to have two sections: 
"First Place" only holds the very first tab and "Everything Else" holds the rest of the tabs. Basically, I want to just add two labels in there to separate things visually.
The user should be able to sort things vertically as if the labels weren't there and move tabs between the two lists.
[This pen](http://codepen.io/davidpm/pen/wKgXGa) should demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

You'll notice that I can't really insert markup into

```
<div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list2">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
```

as I only want the labels to appear one time...

Any ideas?

Comment: I ended up doing: 
`<div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list2" ng-show="$first">{{app.title}}</div>`
...
`<div class="app" ng-repeat="app in list2" ng-show="$index !== 0">{{app.title}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Using `$first` and `$index`:

```
   <div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" class="apps-container screen floatleft" ng-model="list2">
      <div ng-repeat="app in list2">
          <div ng-if="$first">First Place</div>
          <div ng-if="$index == 1">Everything Else</div>
          <div class="app">{{$index}} {{app.title}}</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this pointed me in the right direction, but the problem remained that when you dragged tabs around it would grab both the div.app and the label that was showing